# Attach class to filter

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I was wondering if there is a way to set a CSS style class to the floating filter row of the ag-grid (the one with the class `ag-floating-filter-button`).

In the documentation there is no data about that

EDIT

I am adding columns this way:

```
this.columns = [            
            {
                headerName: "Name", 
                field: "lastName",                 
                cellClass: 'flex items-center',
            },{
                headerName: "Email", 
                field: "email", 
                cellClass: 'flex items-center',    
            }]

[...]

<div className="ag-theme-material table w-full flex flex-1">
                    <AgGridReact                                          
                        rowData={this.props.data}
                        floatingFilter={true}
                        defaultColDef={{sortable: true, filter: "agTextColumnFilter", resizable: true}}
                        columnDefs={this.columns}                          
                    />
                </div>
```

And the result is this

[image: result]

**My need is really simple: color email filter in red**

Comment: Could you share a code snippet for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I added the piece of code